# How to convert below sql query into yii2 code

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

SELECT student_subjects.student_id,student_subjects.subject_id,student_subjects.amount FROM student_subjects where NOT EXISTS(SELECT subject_id from payment_history where student_subjects.subject_id=payment_history.subject_id)

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT student_subjects.student_id,student_subjects.subject_id,student_subjects.amount FROM student_subjects where NOT EXISTS(SELECT subject_id from payment_history where student_subjects.subject_id=payment_history.subject_id)"
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```